# Very strange graphs with ggplot2 geom_violin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I could only reliably reconstruct this problem with a pretty large data set, so I pasted the entire code [to a pastebin](http://pastebin.ca/2465250)
Here is the code without the data part:

```
    # read tmp from the pastebin  

library(ggplot2)
plt <- ggplot(tmp, aes(region, score))
plt1 <- plt + geom_violin(aes(region, score), scale='width', trim=F)  + ylim(0, 1) + ggtitle('with ylim')
plt2 <- plt + geom_violin(aes(region, score), scale='width', trim=F)  + ggtitle('without ylim')
```

Setting y limits for this plot results in pretty ugly "violins":

[image]

[image]

What is this, why does this happen and how to avoid this ugly problem?

BTW, setting `trim=T` solves the problem.

Comment: There should be a badge for such (amusing) output, but I think posting to the ggplot2 bug page would make more sense.

Comment: geom_violin, geom_inverted_hihat, geom_metronome

Comment: You can actually produce this with a simpler dataset: `ggplot(mapping=aes(1, runif(1e3, 0, 1))) + geom_violin(trim=FALSE) + ylim(0, 1)`

Comment: Your `y` variable is barely within [0, 1], so you are of course going to have density falling outside of that. With `stat_density`, this excess density is just cut off, but with `geom_violin`/`stat_ydensity`, the excess is left, and the scale is allowed to extend. With your `ylim` and `trim=F` though, these `y` values outside [0, 1] are kept and just set as `NA`, which screws up the drawing in `geom_polygon`. I think. To avoid the problem, perhaps just set `trim=T` or use `coord_cartesian`?

Comment: @Peyton if you write your comment as an answer I will be able to "accept" it

Comment: @bgbg, I expanded my comment to provide an answer. I hope you find it useful, but let me know if you don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a bit of digging, I think the technical source of the problem is this: Your `y` variable is barely within [0, 1], so you are of course going to have density falling outside of that. With `stat_density`, this excess density is just cut off, but with `geom_violin`/`stat_ydensity`, the excess is left, and the scale is allowed to extend. With your `ylim` and `trim=FALSE` though, these `y` values outside [0, 1] are kept and just set as `NA`, which screws up the drawing in `geom_polygon`. You can actually see this with a smaller example with data in [0, 1]:

```
x <- runif(1e4, 0, 1)
ggplot(mapping=aes(1, x)) + geom_violin(trim=FALSE) + ylim(0, 1)
```

[image: a broken violin plot]

There are a couple of ways around this. The first is to just leave the default `trim=TRUE`:

```
ggplot(mapping=aes(1, x)) + geom_violin() + ylim(0, 1)
```

[image: a violin plot with ylim and trim=TRUE]

Note that `ylim` (`scale_y_continuous`) will actually remove raw data outside of [0, 1] in this case. In your example, you don't have any points outside of this, and neither do I here. But it's something to be aware of. There will also be some padding at the top and bottom, perhaps misleading the viewer to think that there is no density outside of [0, 1].

Perhaps a better solution is to use `coord_cartesian`, which will simply "zoom in" to the graph, leaving the data and resulting density untouched:

```
ggplot(mapping=aes(1, x)) + geom_violin(trim=FALSE) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 1))
```

[image: a violin plot with coord_cartesian]